# Django F expression in boolean expression raises a TypeError exception

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using Django 3.2 in a project. I have a method that compares the value of a field to an integer (see code below).

Django throws an error (which makes sense because of the different types).

My question is - how else am I to implement this check (whilst using F expression to avoid race conditions)?

##### Code

```
def bookmark(self, actor, note=''):
    if self.can_bookmark(actor):
        ct, object_id = self.get_content_info()
        found_objects = self.bookmarks.filter(content_type=ct, object_id=object_id, actor=actor)        
            
        if found_objects:
            # We are unbookmarking
            found_objects.delete()
            self.bookmarks_count = F('bookmarks_count') - 1

            # Sanity check (-ve value may occur if Db has been manipulated manually for instance)
            if self.bookmarks_count < 0:  # <- Barfs here
                self.bookmarks_count = 0

            if self.bookmarks_count == 0: # <- Barfs here too
                self.last_bookmarked = None    

            self.save()            
            return True

        else:
            # Create bookmark object and save it
            if self.create_and_increment(self.bookmarks, actor, note=note):
                self.bookmarks_count = F('bookmarks_count') + 1
                self.last_bookmarked = timezone.now()

                actionable_object = self.actionable_object
                self.save()

                self.refresh_from_db()

                item_bookmarked.send(sender= actionable_object.__class__, instance=actionable_object, event_type = BOOKMARK, actor=actor)  
                return True    

            else:
                return False      
    else:
        # do nothing
        return False
```

### Edit:

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/myproj/models.py", line 455, in bookmark
    if self.bookmarks_count < 0:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'CombinedExpression' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform the sanity check first, or work with [**`Greatest`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest):

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest

self.bookmarks_count = Greatest(F('bookmarks_count') - 1, Value(0))
self.save()
self.refresh_from_db(fields=('bookmarks_count',))
if self.bookmarks_count == 0:
    self.last_bookmarked = None
self.save()
```

Here the [**`.refresh_from_db(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) will ensure that we get the  updated `bookmarks_count`.

---

> **Note**: You do not have to store the number of items of a `ManyToManyField` in another field. You can use [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) when you need to determine this by the database. Storing this explicitly in a field is a form of *data duplication*, and it turns out that keeping these in sync is harder than what one might expect.

Comment: Could you please clarify the Note you added? In this particular model, the number of items is stored as a regular int. The reason I did do that is so that I can run queries against it - my assumption is that it is better (faster queries) to have scalar fields in the db,to query against, as opposed to fields that are computed on the fly - but I may be wrong. If I am wrong., please clarify.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: unless the amount of data is huge, often using a `.annotate(..)` will not be that slow, and it prevents that there eventually is inconsistency between the `bookmarks_count` and the number of `Bookmark` objects: for example if a `User` object is removed, then the related `Bookmark`s will be removed as well, but the `bookmarks_count` will not be updated. While one can of course try to implement all possible scenario's, it is (very) hard to ensure that no such scenario can ever happen that results in inconsistency.